# Add zeros to the left of Number

Tags: java

I know that I can add left zeros to String but what about Long?

I need to put left zeros until the Long size is 10 digits. For example, if it's 8 digits (12345678), it should add 2 left zeros (0012345678)

I want to add this in the getValue() method.

```
public Long getValue() {
    // Should always be 10 digits, If it's 8, add zeros
    return value; 
}
```

**I'm using spring. This issue is that the database that cuts the left zeros. Maybe is there a annotation to avoid extra code?**

Comment: Numbers can not have leading zeros. If you need to save/read numbers with leading zeros, you have to use String.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. A `Long` does not contain data about the `String` representation of its value. In fact, the `Long` is actually stored in binary, not decimal, and the `long` object is unaware of this.

If you want to convert it to a `String` with leading zeroes, `String.format("%017d" , number);` will pad it to make sure it has 10 digits.

Answer (score 3):

In java, a `long` (wrapped in a `Long`) will always be stored on 8 bytes,
There is no way to "add" extra zeros as they're already existing.

Either your database must change its type to `String` and add padding zeros when you store your `Long` object either change your inner code to `String` and add padding zeros when you pull the data from your `Long` in db.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot because a long does not have a leading zero.

A string of characters like 0012345678 is not an integer, 12345678 is.

but there are two way in java to add leading zeroes

**WAY 1: format() method**

```
int number = 9;        
String str = String.format("%04d", 9);  // 0009  
System.out.printf("original number %d, numeric string with padding : %s", 9, str);
```

**WAY 2 :  DecimalFormat**

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000");
 String c = df.format(9);   // 0009
 String a = df.format(99);  // 0099
 String b = df.format(999); // 0999
```

**but in both case you get string instead of Long**

[for more reading](https://www.java67.com/2014/10/how-to-pad-numbers-with-leading-zeroes-in-Java-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
int number = 12345678;        
String str = String.format("%10d", number);    
System.out.println("original number %d, numeric string with padding : %s", number, str);
```